# How can I insert a vertex between two currently connected vertexes?

Tags: titan, gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

I am trying to to grips with Gremlin.  Having thoroughly read the documentation I still appear to be struggling with it conceptually.

I am creating a basic newsfeed, following the model found in the Neo4j documentation here:

http://neo4j.com/docs/snapshot/cypher-cookbook-newsfeed.html

I am actually using titandb, but am following the same sort of principles/schema as shown above.

So far I have created a graph of `user` vertexes, which are connected via `friend` edges.

And I am able to add a new `post` vertex and connect it via a `posted` edge to a `user` vertex like so:

```
 def activity = graph.addVertex(T.label, "post");
 activity.property("post_id", post_id);
 activity.property("time", time);
 activity.property("body", body);

 def g = graph.traversal();
 def user = g.V().hasLabel("user").has("userid", userid).next();
 user.addEdge("posted", activity, "time", time);
```

However, I need to be able to do the following in a single Gremlin script:

1. Create the new `post` vertex, as above.
2. Remove the old `posted` edge between the `user` and any currently connected `post` vertex. But **only if**, a post currently exists.
3. Attach the new `post` vertex to the `user` with a new `posted` edge.
4. Then finally, if there was a previous `post` vertex, attach it to the newly added `post` vertex via a `next` edge.  Ultimately creating long streams of posts for each user.

I've been playing around, using trial and error, for what seems like hours now, and just cannot seem to get my head around it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way (using a single traversal):

**Create the initial graph with a single user:**

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> g.addV("user").property("userid", 123)
==>v[0]
```

**Add the first post:**

```
gremlin> g.V().has("user", "userid", 123).as("user").      /* find the user                            */
           addV("post").as("p").property("post_id", 1).    /* add a new post                           */
             property("time", System.currentTimeMillis()).
             property("body", "bla bla").
           addE("posted").from("user").as("e").            /* connect user and post                    */
             property("time", System.currentTimeMillis()).
           outV().                                         /* traverse to user                         */
           outE("posted").where(neq("e")).as("o").         /* traverse to any pre-existing posted edge */
           inV().                                          /* traverse to pre-existing post            */
           addE("next").to("p").                           /* connect it with the new post             */
           select("o").drop()                              /* drop the old posted edge                 */

gremlin> // check
gremlin> g.V().not(inE()).repeat(union(outE("posted").inV(), inE("next").outV())).until(__.not(union(outE("posted"), inE("next")))).path().by(label)
==>[user, posted, post]
```

**Add another post (same query):**

```
gremlin> g.V().has("user", "userid", 123).as("user").
           addV("post").as("p").property("post_id", 1).
             property("time", System.currentTimeMillis()).
             property("body", "bla bla").
           addE("posted").from("user").as("e").
             property("time", System.currentTimeMillis()).
           outV().
           outE("posted").where(neq("e")).as("o").
           inV().
           addE("next").to("p").
           select("o").drop()

gremlin> // check
gremlin> g.V().not(inE()).repeat(union(outE("posted").inV(), inE("next").outV())).until(__.not(union(outE("posted"), inE("next")))).path().by(label)
==>[user, posted, post, next, post]
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way you might do it:

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerGraph.open()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> createPost = { user, post -> 
......1>   u = g.V().has('userId', user).next()
......2>   previous = g.V(u).outE('posted').inV().tryNext().orElse(null)
......3>   g.V(u).outE('posted').drop().iterate()
......4>   activity = graph.addVertex(T.label, "post", "postId", post)
......5>   u.addEdge("posted", activity)  
......6> 
......6>   if (null != previous) previous.addEdge('next', activity)
......7> 
......7>   // with titan you would want to commit the transaction
......8>   // graph.tx().commit()
......9> }
==>groovysh_evaluate$_run_closure1@522b2631
```

Then add a user and call the `createPost()` function a few times:

```
gremlin> user = g.addV(label,"user", "userId", "me").next()
==>v[0]
gremlin> createPost("me",1)
gremlin> createPost("me",2)
==>e[8][2-next->5]
gremlin> createPost("me",3)
==>e[12][5-next->9]
gremlin> createPost("me",4)
==>e[16][9-next->13]
gremlin> createPost("me",5)
==>e[20][13-next->17]
```

You can see the "posted" edge aimed at the newest "post" vertex:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('userId','me').outE()
==>e[19][0-posted->17]
```

If we traverse out from there along the incoming "next" edge you can get to the previous post:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('userId','me').out('posted').in('next')
==>v[13]
```

The following shows three previous posts:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('userId','me').out('posted').in('next').in('next')
==>v[9]
```

You can also traverse to arbitrary depth along `next`:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('userId','me').
               out('posted').
               repeat(__.in('next')).
                 until(inE().count().is(0)).emit().
               path().
                 by(choose(label().is('post'),
                      values('postId'),
                      values('userId')))
==>[me,5,4]
==>[me,5,4,3]
==>[me,5,4,3,2]
==>[me,5,4,3,2,1]
```

Comment: A fantastic answer, thank you.  This has helped immeasurably.

Comment: I have however, accepted Daniels answer, as his example does it in a single traversal.  From my limited understanding, this should be preferable should it not?  Regardless, your answer really helped me to understand several key concepts.  Many thanks.

Comment: I purposely didn't do a single traversal for purpose of you getting at key concepts - so at least that mission was accomplished :)